# Draw a foliation on the sphere

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to do the following follition on the sphere.

[image]

So far I have the following

[image]

With the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\textwidth 16cm
\textheight 23cm
\oddsidemargin 0.8cm
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2.4cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-base, tkz-fct, tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}% mapas mentales
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{multirow}%%para combinar filas en tablas.
\usepackage{array}%%para tablas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \subfigure []{ \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 3.0]
            
            % Create a point (P)
            \coordinate (Px) at (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P1x) at (- 1/1.4 ,  {1/sqrt(2)}, 0);
            \coordinate (P2x) at ( 1/1.4,-{1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P3x) at (-1/1.4 , -{1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P4x) at (0, {1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P5x) at (0, -{1/sqrt(2)}, 0);
            
            
                
            
            
            Draw shaded circle
            \shade[ball color = lightgray,
            opacity = 0.5
            ] (0,0,0) circle (1cm);
            
            
            
            
            %draw the equator
            
            %red
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
        
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{180}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            
            %blue
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{45}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{225}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
                
                
            
            
            
            %Draw the near curve to equator
            
            %red
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{325}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{325}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            %blue
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{48}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{48}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{232}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{232}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            
                %Great circle in blue   
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{180};
            \draw[
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:160:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{340};
            \draw[dashed,
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:200:1);
            
            
            %Great circle in red
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{90}{100};
            \draw[
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:170:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{90}{270};
            \draw[dashed,
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:190:1);
            

            
            % Axes in 3 d coordinate system
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (2.2,0,0)node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.70,0)node[right]{$y$};
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.70)node[right]{$z$};
            \draw[dashed, gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (-2.2,0,0);
            \draw[dashed, gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1.70,0);
            
        
            
            % Add small circle at (P)
            \draw[fill = green] (Px) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P1x) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P2x) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P3x) circle (0.7pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{center}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

My problem now is that I haven't been able to draw the smooth curve that links the lines above and below the equator like the curves on the ellipsoid.

I improve my code and get the following

[image]

With the following code, (the preamble is the same as above)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\textwidth 16cm
\textheight 23cm
\oddsidemargin 0.8cm
\addtolength{\voffset}{-2.4cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-0.5cm}

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-base, tkz-fct, tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}% mapas mentales
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{multirow}%%para combinar filas en tablas.
\usepackage{array}%%para tablas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}

\rotatebox{0}{  \subfigure []{ \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 3.0]
            
            % Create a point (P)
            \coordinate (Px) at (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P1x) at (- 1/1.4 ,  {1/sqrt(2)}, 0);
            \coordinate (P2x) at ( 1/1.4,-{1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P3x) at (-1/1.4 , -{1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P4x) at (0, {1/sqrt(2)},0);
            \coordinate (P5x) at (0, -{1/sqrt(2)}, 0);
            
            
        
            
            Draw shaded circle
            \shade[ball color = lightgray,
            opacity = 0.5
            ] (0,0,0) circle (1cm);
            
            
            
            
            %draw the equator
            
            %red
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
        
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{180}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            
            %blue
            %left
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{45}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{270}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{225}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:45:1);
            
                
                
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     
            
            
            %Draw the  curve near the equator
            
            %red
            
            %front red 1
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:42:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{318}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:42:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:41.3:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{319}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:41:1);
            
            
            %front red 2
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{318}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:39.3:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{319}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            
            
            %back red 1
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            
                %back red 2
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:38:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:38:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            
            
            
            
            
            %blue
            
            %right blue 1
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{44.9}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:42:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{45}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:41:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            
            
            %right blue 2
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{46.5}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{46.7}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            
            
            
            %left blue 1
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{277}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:40:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{226}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{276}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:39:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{225}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,-1/8) arc (0:45:1);
            
            
            
            %left blue 2
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{277}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:38:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{226}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{276}{0}{0};
            \draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:37:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{225}{0}{0};
            \draw[dashed, tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (0.968,0,-1/4) arc (0:43:1);
            
            
            
            
            
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%55
            
            
                %Great circle in blue   
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{180};
            \draw[
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:160:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{340};
            \draw[dashed,
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            blue
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:200:1);
            
            
            
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            
            
            %Great circle in red
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{90}{100};
            \draw[
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:170:1);
            
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{180}{90}{270};
            \draw[dashed,
            tdplot_rotated_coords,
            red
            ] (1,0,0) arc (0:190:1);
            

            
            % Axes in 3 d coordinate system
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (2.2,0,0)node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.70,0)node[right]{$y$};
            \draw[-stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.70)node[right]{$z$};
            \draw[dashed, gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (-2.2,0,0);
            \draw[dashed, gray, -stealth] (0,0,0) -- (0,-1.70,0);
            
        
            
            % Add small circle at (P)
            \draw[fill = green] (Px) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P1x) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P2x) circle (0.7pt);
            \draw[fill = green] (P3x) circle (0.7pt);
            
            
            
            
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},1/4) circle (0.3pt); 
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.654, {1/sqrt(2.6)},0.1875) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.735, {1/sqrt(3)},1/8) circle (0.3pt);
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.834, {1/sqrt(3.3)},0) circle (0.3pt);
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.806, {1/sqrt(3)},-1/8) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.761, {1/sqrt(2.6)},-0.1875) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/4) circle (0.3pt);    
            
        
        
        
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
            
            
            % completing of D1, point on the first quadrant
            
            %blue front 1
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue] (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},1/8) .. controls (0.731, {1/sqrt(2.2)},1/10) and (0.747, {1/sqrt(2.3)},1/12) .. (0.763, {1/sqrt(2.4)},0) .. controls (0.747, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/12) and (0.731, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/10) .. (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/8);
            
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue] (1/1.4, -{1/sqrt(2)},1/8) .. controls (0.731, -{1/sqrt(2.2)},1/10) and (0.747, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},1/12) .. (0.763, -{1/sqrt(2.4)},0) .. controls (0.747, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/12) and (0.731, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/10) .. (1/1.4, -{1/sqrt(2)},-1/8);
            
            %blue front 2
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue] (0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},1/4) .. controls (0.654, {1/sqrt(2.6)},0.1875) and (0.735, {1/sqrt(3)},1/8) .. (0.816, {1/sqrt(3)},0) .. controls (0.806, {1/sqrt(3)},-1/8) and (0.761, {1/sqrt(2.6)},-0.1875) .. (0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/4);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue] (0.661, -{1/sqrt(2)},1/4) .. controls (0.654, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},0.1875) and (0.735, -{1/sqrt(3)},1/8) .. (0.829, -{1/sqrt(3.2)},0) .. controls (0.806, -{1/sqrt(3)},-1/8) and (0.761, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},-0.1875) .. (0.661, -{1/sqrt(2)},-1/4);
            
        
            %blue back 1
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue, dashed] (-1/1.4, -{1/sqrt(2)},1/8) .. controls (-0.731, -{1/sqrt(2.2)},1/10) and (-0.747, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},1/12) .. (-0.763, -{1/sqrt(2.4)},0) .. controls (-0.747, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/12) and (-0.731, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/10) .. (-1/1.4, -{1/sqrt(2)},-1/8);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue, dashed] (-1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},1/8) .. controls (-0.731, {1/sqrt(2.2)},1/10) and (-0.747, {1/sqrt(2.3)},1/12) .. (-0.763, {1/sqrt(2.4)},0) .. controls (-0.747, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/12) and (-0.731, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/10) .. (-1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/8);
            
            %blue back 2
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue, dashed] (-0.661, -{1/sqrt(2)},1/4) .. controls (-0.779, -{1/sqrt(2.8)},0.1875) and (-0.735, -{1/sqrt(3)},1/8) .. (-0.829, -{1/sqrt(3.2)},0) .. controls (-0.806, -{1/sqrt(3)},-1/8) and (-0.779, -{1/sqrt(2.8)},-0.1875) .. (-0.661, -{1/sqrt(2)},-1/4);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, blue, dashed] (-0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},1/4) .. controls (-0.779, {1/sqrt(2.8)},0.1875) and (-0.735,{1/sqrt(3)},1/8) .. (-0.829, {1/sqrt(3.2)},0) .. controls (-0.806, {1/sqrt(3)},-1/8) and (-0.779, {1/sqrt(2.8)},-0.1875) .. (-0.661, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/4);
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.743, {1/sqrt(2.6)},1/4) circle (0.3pt);   
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.598, {1/sqrt(2.2)},0.1875) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.535, {1/sqrt(1.7)},1/8) circle (0.3pt);
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.557, {1/sqrt(1.45)},0) circle (0.3pt);
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.599, -{1/sqrt(1.6)}, -1/8) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.676, -{1/sqrt(2.2)}, -1/4) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},-1/4) circle (0.3pt);
            
            
            
            
            
            %front red 1
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (0.741, {1/sqrt(2.3)},1/8) .. controls (0.654, {1/sqrt(1.8)},1/10) and (0.638, {1/sqrt(1.7)},1/16) .. (0.633, {1/sqrt(1.67)},0) .. controls (0.638, {1/sqrt(1.7)},-1/16) and (0.654, {1/sqrt(1.8)},-1/10) .. (0.741, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/8);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (0.741, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},1/8) .. controls (0.654, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},1/10) and (0.638, -{1/sqrt(1.7)},1/16) .. (0.633, -{1/sqrt(1.67)},0) .. controls (0.638, -{1/sqrt(1.7)},-1/16) and (0.654, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},-1/10) .. (0.741, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/8);
            
            
            %front red 2
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (0.743, {1/sqrt(2.6)},1/4) .. controls (0.598, {1/sqrt(2.2)},0.1875) and (0.535, {1/sqrt(1.7)},1/8) .. (0.577, {1/sqrt(1.5)},0) .. controls (0.599, {1/sqrt(1.6)}, -1/8) and (0.395, {1/sqrt(2.2)}, -1/3) .. (0.743, {1/sqrt(2.6)},-1/4);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},1/4) .. controls (0.598, -{1/sqrt(2.2)},0.1875) and (0.535, -{1/sqrt(1.7)},1/8) .. (0.577, -{1/sqrt(1.5)},0) .. controls (0.599, -{1/sqrt(1.6)}, -1/8) and (0.676, -{1/sqrt(2.2)}, -1/4) .. (0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)}, -1/4);
            
            
            %back red 1
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red, dashed] (-0.741, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},1/8) .. controls (-0.654, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},1/10) and (-0.638, -{1/sqrt(1.7)},1/16) .. (-0.633, -{1/sqrt(1.67)},0) .. controls (-0.638, -{1/sqrt(1.7)},-1/16) and (-0.654, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},-1/10) .. (-0.741, -{1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/8);
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red, dashed] (-0.741, {1/sqrt(2.3)},1/8) .. controls (-0.654, {1/sqrt(1.8)},1/10) and (-0.638, {1/sqrt(1.7)},1/16) .. (-0.633, {1/sqrt(1.67)},0) .. controls (-0.638, {1/sqrt(1.7)},-1/16) and (-0.654, {1/sqrt(1.8)},-1/10) .. (-0.741, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/8);
            
            %back red 2
            
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red, dashed] (-0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},1/4) .. controls (-0.579, -{1/sqrt(1.57)},1/6) and (-0.612, -{1/sqrt(1.6)},1/8) .. (-0.577, -{1/sqrt(1.5)},0) .. controls (-0.612, -{1/sqrt(1.6)},-1/8) and (-0.579, -{1/sqrt(1.57)},-1/6) .. (-0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},-1/4);
            
            
            
            
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},1/4) circle (0.3pt); 
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.645, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},1/6) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.612, -{1/sqrt(1.6)},1/8) circle (0.3pt);
                
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.534, -{1/sqrt(1.4)},0) circle (0.3pt);
                
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.612, -{1/sqrt(1.6)},-1/8) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.645, -{1/sqrt(1.8)},-1/6) circle (0.3pt);
            %\draw[fill = red] (-0.743, -{1/sqrt(2.6)},-1/4) circle (0.3pt);
            
            
            
            %\draw[blue,rotate=160] (Px) ellipse (0.3 and 0.12);
            %\draw[blue, rotate=4] (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/8) arc(270:90: 0.2cm and 0.09cm);
            
            
            
            %\draw [green] plot [smooth ] coordinates {(1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},1/8) (0.749, {1/sqrt(2.3)},1/16) (0.784, {1/sqrt(2.6)},0) (0.749, {1/sqrt(2.3)},-1/16) (1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},-1/8)};
            
                
            %\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{180}{180};
            %\draw[ tdplot_rotated_coords,
            %red
            %] (-1/1.4, {1/sqrt(2)},1/8) arc (0:180:1/4);   

\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But my curves still don't appear smooth, particularly of the left spot. How to improve it?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your code so people can compile it. Do you have the equation for the curve you want to draw? Have you considered doing this in an external application?

Comment: Hi. Going put the preambule in the code, but my preambule is very long since I'm new in tikz and perhaps I don't need all things.